# Two relationship tables between two mater tables

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-annotations

I have two tables which map relationship.

[image]

There are WP_Post and WP_Term which are master data.

There is WP_Term_Relationship which has relationship between WP_Post and WP_Term_Taxonomy 
Tabels.

There is WP_Term_Taxonomy which has relationship between WP_Term_Relationship and WP_Term Tabels.

I have two classes for Event(Post) and SchoolCategory(Term). Post has list of Term field. I am try to get all terms corresponding Post. But there are two relation tables in between so not able to map.

```
public class Event {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private long id;

@Column(name = "name")
private String name;

//need mapping here.
private List<SchoolCategory> schoolCategories;
```

}

Any one have any idea. Could you please put your thoughts and views. I am using Hibernate Annotation.

Comment: Your question is quite confusing. First you described somthing about WP_Post,WP_Term,WP_Term_Taxonomy and WP_Term_Relationship and at the last you asking about Event(Post) and SchoolCategory(Term). By the way according to your sentace `I am try to get all terms corresponding Post` you have to use `one-to-many` relationship

Answer (score 0):

I guess it should be like this :

```
@Table(name = "event")
public class Event {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private long id;

@Column(name = "name")
private String name;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "event")
private List<SchoolCategory> schoolCategories;
}
```